# Builds with referenced assemblies on the network

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

We are starting a new project, and we would like to put some of the assembly references on a networked drive (in the future, these assemblies will be "dropped" by a build server on to the network location).

I had thought that I read somewhere that Visual Studio is smart about network locations, and that when it detects an assembly on a network drive, it would copy the assembly locally and only update it if the assembly changes.  I cannot seem to replicate that behavior, though -- every time I build (even a "normal" build, not a rebuild), VS re-downloads the referenced assemblies from the network connection.  If your connection happens to be over a VPN, you can really feel it (adds *minutes* to the build time).

Was I wrong about VS's build behavior, or is there something that I need to do to enable it?

Comment: Have you considered using an internal [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) [repository](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Hosting%20Your%20Own%20Local%20and%20Remote%20NuPack%20Feeds)?

Comment: I've read about NuGet (but haven't used it yet).  Some of these assemblies might change frequently -- like daily if we use a build server.  Would NuGet be suitable for that?

Comment: you can keep an internal repository (basically, a shared folder with packages) that your build script updates. Maybe you didn't notice it, but the "repository" word in my last comment links to the docs for setting up that repository (again it's just a shared folder). You may run into the problem of getting tons of old versions of your packages lying around though. Not sure if that's a problem for you and how you want to deal with that.

Comment: I think it's OK to use NuGet with frequently updating binaries, though they probably shouldn't be kept under source control.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes  Thank you for the suggestion, but it doesn't look as though NuGet will work for us.  What I really want is a "set it and forget it" solution.  I have tested NuGet with TFS, and as nearly as I can tell, NuGet doesn't support team development.  For example:  Suppose I add a package to my project and check it in.  If you do a get latest, you will have missing references, and you will have to "just know" to NuGet the package.  Am I missing something?  Maybe there is a feature that I don't know about?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Link is broken. The new link is [here](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the references local but introduce a pre-build step to copy them down locally using robocopy.  Robocopy is part of the OS in Vista onwards and can be installed as part of the resource kit in previous version of windows (like XP).

Here is an msbuild target to invoke robocopy:

```
  <Target Name="SyncReferences">

    <Message Text="RemoteReferencesRoot:$(RemoteReferencesRoot)" />
    <Message Text="LocalReferencesRoot:$(LocalReferencesRoot)" />

    <!-- ensure required properties are set -->
    <Error Condition="'$(RemoteReferencesRoot)'==''" Text="RemoteReferencesRoot property not set." />
    <Error Condition="'$(LocalReferencesRoot)'==''" Text="LocalReferencesRoot property not set." />

    <!-- Robocopy can't handle trailing slash nicely the way we're going to call it -->
    <Error Condition="HasTrailingSlash('$(RemoteReferencesRoot)')" Text="RemoteReferencesRoot has a trailing slash.  '$(RemoteReferencesRoot)'" />
    <Error Condition="HasTrailingSlash('$(LocalReferencesRoot)')" Text="LocalReferencesRoot has a trailing slash.  '$(LocalReferencesRoot)'" />

    <!-- ensure source and target directories exist -->
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(RemoteReferencesRoot)')" Text="$(RemoteReferencesRoot) does not exist." />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(LocalReferencesRoot)')" Text="$(LocalReferencesRoot) does not exist." />

    <!-- remember to ignore the exit code as robocopy can return values other than 0 -->
    <Exec Command='Robocopy /mir /z "$(RemoteReferencesRoot)" "$(LocalReferencesRoot)"' IgnoreExitCode='true'>
      <Output PropertyName="RoboCopyExitCode" TaskParameter="ExitCode"/>
    </Exec>

    <Message Text="RoboCopyExitCode:$(RoboCopyExitCode)" />

    <!--Robocopy exit code:--> 
    <!-- 0  No errors occurred and no files were copied.--> 
    <!-- 1  One of more files were copied successfully.--> 
    <!-- 2  Extra files or directories were detected.  Examine the log file for more information.--> 
    <!-- 4  Mismatched files or directories were detected.  Examine the log file for more information.--> 
    <!-- 8  Some files or directories could not be copied and the retry limit was exceeded.--> 
    <!-- 16 Robocopy did not copy any files.  Check the command line parameters and verify that Robocopy has enough rights to write to the destination folder.--> 
    <Error Condition="$(RoboCopyExitCode)>3" Text="Robocopy returned exit code '$(RoboCopyExitCode)' which indicates a failure." />

  </Target>
```

Comment: I actually ended up building both a NuGet and Robocopy test case for this, and decided that if we have to do much of this, Robocopy would be the way to go for now (I really liked NuGet, though, and it looks as though they are working on the team issue).  +1 and answer for including the MSBuild target!

Answer (score 2):

Here's [another option for you](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsprofiler/thread/e2f645c4-0230-4fa7-87e7-a2b5b8b5dbfb). Basically adding a pre-build event that checks to see if the network location assemblies are newer.

Answer (score 0):

What I can recommend is the procedure we use at my company. We have a networked repository of internal assemblies, let's call it `\\AssembliesRepository`. However, we don't directly reference off of it (what happens if you lose network connectivity?). Instead, each machine has a local folder, let's go with `C:\Assemblies`, that mirrors `\\AssembliesRepository`. We use [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) to handle mirroring the two locations, and Task Scheduler to run SyncToy at whatever interval we deem appropriate (currently every 15 minutes during the work day). Using this setup, we never need direct access to `\\AssembliesRepository`, we just drop assemblies in the local folder, and SyncToy handles the rest. Every 15 minutes we have new assemblies, so we build with the latest internal assemblies at all times. Even the build server is setup this way. I can't promise this works for you, but it certainly reduces burden on the network either way.